# Problem with stoi function (abort() has been called)

Tags: c++

I receive a string in the form `"(mx+n)(px+q)"`. My task is to transform the string to this form: `ax^2+bx+c`. My tactic is to pull all the numbers out of the brackets and put them together to form an equation. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    int vals[4]; 
    string temp = ""; 
    char var = '\0';
    
    string eq = "(-h-7)(4h+3)";

    for (int i = 0; i < eq.length(); i++)
    {
        if (eq[i] == '(') eq[i] = '\0'; 
        else if (eq[i] == ')') eq[i] = ' '; 

        if (isalpha(eq[i]) && (eq[i - 1] == '-' || eq[i - 1] == '\0'))
            var = eq[i]; eq[i] = '1';
        }
        else if (isalpha(eq[i]) && isdigit(eq[i - 1])) 
            eq[i] = '\0';

    } // "(-h-7)(4h+3)" => "-1-7 4+3 " <- Result

    cout << eq << endl;

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < eq.length(); i++)
    {
        temp += eq[i];

        if ( (eq[i + 1] == '-' || eq[i + 1] == '+' || eq[i + 1] == ' ') && (eq[i + 2] != '-') )
        {
            vals[j] = stoi(temp); //THE ERROR HERE: std::invalid_argument. (I've found this error by debugging)
            j++;
            temp = "";
        }

    } // The result should be: "-1-7 4+3 " => vals = {-1, -7, 4, 3}
    
    temp += to_string(vals[0] * vals[2]) + var + "^2";

    ( (vals[0] * vals[3] + vals[1] * vals[2]) >= 0) ? temp += '+' + to_string(vals[0] * vals[3] + vals[1] * vals[2]) + var : temp += to_string(vals[0] * vals[3] + vals[1] * vals[2]) + var;
    ((vals[1] * vals[3]) >= 0) ? temp += '+' + to_string(vals[1] * vals[3]) : temp += to_string(vals[1] * vals[3]);
    //Forming an equation ax^2+bx+c
    cout << temp << endl;
    
    system("pause>0");

}
```

As I continued debugging, I found another error in `string` library, in `stoi` function:

```
Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved 
across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a function 
declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared 
with a different calling convention.
```

So I am sure that the problem is with `stoi` function.

But if I create a new variable `string a = "-1-7 4+3 ";`(a variable which is without brackets and variables already (it has not went through the first `for` loop) ) and use the second `for` loop to this variable, everything goes without the error (what am I trying to say is that the problem is with variable `eq` and first `for` loop, I suppose)

How to fix the problem? Please ask me if you did not understand something. I will also appreciate your advice on how to optimise my code.

Comment: Did you change compiler settings for the calling convention? Looks like your compiling with a different calling convention then the calling convention your library was compiled with.

Comment: [Your code fails to compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aebd8342bfade176).

Comment: Calling convention? Where can I read more about it? I tried to read some articles but I did not understand how to check the library's convention; what convention should I use and how to apply it.

Comment: @fabian I've deleted all the brackets in the first ```for``` loop.

Comment: Note: `if (isalpha(eq[i]) && (eq[i - 1] == '-' || eq[i - 1] == '\0'))` seems to have lost its open brace in translation.

Comment: Where do you get the message about calling convention from? If you're getting a `std::invalid_argument` exception when running the code, then you can see why that might be: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol

Answer (score 0):

I made something more general. I tested it with several expressions and it seems ok to me, but it is possible to have some undiscovered bug in it. I hope it suits you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>

std::vector<std::string> str_split(const std::string &str, std::string delim, bool include_delim = false)
{
  std::vector<std::string> elements;
  std::size_t prev = 0, pos;
  bool skipped= false;
  while ((pos = str.find_first_of(delim, prev)) != std::string::npos) {
    if (pos > prev) {
        elements.push_back(
          include_delim && prev > 0 ? 
            str.substr(prev - 1, pos - prev + int(skipped)) : str.substr(prev, pos - prev));
        skipped = false;
    } else {
      skipped = true;
    }
    prev = pos + 1;
  }
  if (prev < str.length()) {
      elements.push_back(
        include_delim && prev > 0 ? 
          str.substr(prev - 1, std::string::npos) : str.substr(prev,std::string::npos));
  }

  return elements;
}

std::string trim(std::string str)
{
  static const std::string WHITESPACE_CHARS(" \t\n\r\f\v");
  str.erase(0, str.find_first_not_of(WHITESPACE_CHARS));
  str.erase(str.find_last_not_of(WHITESPACE_CHARS) + 1);
  return str;
}

std::string algebraic_expansions(std::string str) 
{
  // Remove spaces from the expression
  str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), ' '), str.end());

  // Lower case X->x
  std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(),
    [](unsigned char c){ return std::tolower(c); });
  
  // Replace '(' and ')' with space so it will be easy to split it,
  std::replace_if(str.begin(), str.end(), [](char c) {
    return c == '(' || c == ')' ? true : false;
  }, ' ');

  str = trim(str);
  auto multiplied_elements = str_split(str, " ");

  // Each vector element represent the expression between the bracets i.e (<expression>)
  // The map key is the power of X, and the value represent the number multiplied by X^n
  std::vector<std::map<int, int>> parsed_expression;

  for (const auto& multiplied_element : multiplied_elements) {
    auto products = str_split(multiplied_element, "+-", true);
    for (auto& product : products) {
      product.erase(std::remove(product.begin(), product.end(), '+'), product.end());
    }
    
    // Reserve room for the parsed expression
    parsed_expression.push_back({});
    for (const auto &product : products) {
      auto pos1 = product.find('x');

      // Number not multiplied by X
      if (pos1 == std::string::npos) {
        parsed_expression.back()[0] += std::stoi(product);
        continue;
      }

      // Number is multiplied by x:
      
      // Find the power
      auto pos2 = product.find('^');

      // The power is 1
      if (pos2 == std::string::npos) {
        // If X multiplier is invisible 1
        if (pos1 == 0) {
          parsed_expression.back()[1] += 1;
          continue;
        }
        std::string num_str(product, 0, pos1);
        parsed_expression.back()[1] += std::stoi(num_str);
        continue;
      }

      // The power is greater than 1
      auto pow_str = product.substr(pos2 + 1);
      auto xpow = std::stoi(pow_str);

      // If X multiplier is invisible 1
      if (pos1 == 0) {
        parsed_expression.back()[xpow] += 1;
        continue;
      }
      std::string num_str(product, 0, pos1);
      parsed_expression.back()[xpow] += std::stoi(num_str);
    }
  }

  std::map<int, int> expansion = parsed_expression.front();

  for (auto it = std::next(parsed_expression.begin()); it != parsed_expression.end(); it++) {
    std::map<int, int> expansion_tmp;
    for (auto exp : expansion) {
      auto& sum_of_products = *it;
      for (const auto &product : sum_of_products) {
        auto new_pow = exp.first + product.first;
        auto new_num = exp.second * product.second;
        expansion_tmp[new_pow] += new_num;
      }
    }
    expansion = std::move(expansion_tmp);
  }

  // Print
  std::ostringstream oss;
  for (auto it = expansion.rbegin(); it != expansion.rend(); it++) {
    auto num = it->second;
    auto xpow = it->first;

    if (!num) {
      continue;
    }
    
    if (it != expansion.rbegin() && num > 0) {
      oss << "+";
    }

    if (num != 1) {
      oss << num;
    }
    if (xpow == 1) {
      oss << "x";
    } else if (xpow > 1) {
      oss << "x^" << xpow;
    }
  }
  return oss.str();
}

int main() {

  std::string ex("(-1+x^2)(5x+2x^3)(1+x)");

  std::cout << algebraic_expansions(ex) <<"\n";
}
```